# Is it possible to use tuples in c++ with Gurobi?

Tags: c++, tuples, gurobi

I am trying to solve a SOCP using Gurobi, in a C++ project. From what I know, Gurobi does not support complex numbers, but I have seen that with python it is possible to use tuples as variables, which it would be a great alternative.

However, I've tried to search online and I couldn't find anything about using tuples with Gurobi in C++. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of more research (and after implementing the code I needed in Python), I'll post an answer to my own question. In the Gurobi documentation, the developers admit themselves that the Python API offers more in comparison with the API of other programming languages:

> If you don't have a strong preference, we recommend that you use our Python® interface, which provides a number of benefits. First, Python is a very nice programming language that can be used for anything from experimentation to prototyping to deployment. Beyond this, though, our Python interface includes a set of higher-level modeling constructs that make it much easier to build optimization models.

So, I "solved" the problem by modelling and solving the SOCP with a Python script, which is called by my C++ code and to which I'm passing back the result of the optimization process.